# Wpf Highlight ListViewItem On Drag Drop

Tags: c#, wpf

In my WPF application,I need to highlight ListViewItem whenever something is about to drop on it. I override  OnDragEnter, OnDragOver, OnDragLeave etc of ListViewItem to apply my styles(say change background). It is working fine. but after dropping somthing on a listview item, when i click the listview items the selection and mouseover effects are not working properly.How can i solve this?

```
public class CustomListViewItem : ListViewItem
{
    protected override void OnDragOver(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Green;
        base.OnDragOver(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDragEnter(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Background = Brushes.Green;
        base.OnDragEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnDragLeave(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsSelected)
        {
            this.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
            this.BorderBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
        }
        base.OnDragLeave(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After doing DragDrop your local value has precedence over selection and mouseover effects by style (see [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx#listing)
).

Try [DependencyObject.ClearValue Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597465.aspx):

```
protected override void OnDragLeave(System.Windows.DragEventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsSelected)
    {
        this.ClearValue(BackgroundProperty);
        this.ClearValue(BorderBrushProperty);
    }
    base.OnDragLeave(e);
}
```